# how to get the objects of specific field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Tn the following code the User.objects returns the `"url","username","email","groups"`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    #     TODO return only usernames and urls without emails for privacy purpeses
    # User.objects.username
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

But I also create the following model for the user avatar

```
class TheUserProfiel(models.Model):
    TheUser = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    personalityInformation = models.CharField(
        max_length=9999999, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

## So, HOW to make the `UserViewSet` to return all of these `"url","username","email","groups"` in addition to the `"avatar"` field in the same view

- I tried before to create two views and to combine them in the frontend but it got very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply by updating the `UserSerializer`

```
serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

In the serializers, you had define `UserSerializer`. In that serializer update the fields attribute of  meta class to include avatar.

```
UserSerializer(...):
     ...
     class Meta:
         ...
         fields = (....., 'avatar')
```

Comment: You mean just like this
`
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'username', 'email', 'groups', 'avatar']
`
This does't work because I probably need to update `model = User` as well.

Comment: You can always create new serializer and use it. How far I am able to understand form your code, you are not using this endpoint for authenticating users. So you can make new serializer and update the serializer class of your viewset